# Ansible etd lookup not working

Tags: ansible

I'm testing etcd as permanent storage for Ansible's dynamic variables.

Somehow I'm not able to get `{{lookup('etcd', '/key')}}` to return the value for the key.

After checking the [etcd.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/etcd.py) the only thing poping out is the variable for ANSIBLE_ETCD_URL which has been exported `export ANSIBLE_ETCD_URL='http://localhost:2379'`

**play**:

```
- name: lookup etcd
  debug: {msg: "{{lookup('etcd', '/key')}}"}
```

**etcd value:**

```
$ etcdctl get key
value
```

**What I'm getting in Ansible:**

```
TASK [lookup etcd] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/michal/gits/softcat/platforms-ansible-plays/when_defined.yaml:37
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

**setup:**
etcd Version: 2.2.5
ansible 2.3.2.0
pyetcd (1.7.2)

**Question:**
How can I get this working, is there an extra python library needed for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sorted**,

I was missing the one more variable ANSIBLE_ETCD_VERSION once set to v2 it started to work.

`export ANSIBLE_ETCD_VERSION=v2`